# Why can't I send an item from the auction house to my stash?

Tags: diablo-iii

I bought a spiffy crossbow from the auction house. Unfortunately, when I go to the 'completed' tab and click 'send item to stash', I'm getting an error message that the item can't be sent:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there some kind of waiting period before I can actually receive my item?

Comment: Mostly like no space in your stash, but again Blizzard could've come up with a better error message...

Comment: I'm thinking a "no space in your stash" message would be appropriate X.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common cause of this is having a stash without sufficient space to accept the item.  I'd suggest confirming that you have space in your stash first.

Answer (score 0):

Stash is the chest inside the game, not the inventory of the player. Make sure the stash chest has room in it before you use the auction house